# What is best way to manage multiple related repositories with git?

Tags: git, tfs

I have some huge projects and want to move from TFS to Git. For example, I have three projects: rep_test_sample, rep_test_edition, rep_test_core. Their reference relationship is following. The last two projects "rep_test_core" and "rep_test_edition" are infrastructure projects, they will be referenced by some other projects (actually, the infrastructure projects count is about 70). 
[image]

I tried to create three repositories for each project. And the local structure is following:
/dev
/dev/rep_test_core/
/dev/rep_test_edition/
/dev/rep_test_sample/ (I have several other sample projects as well)

I can clone three repositories one by one, after code changes on three projects, I need to check the status and commit one repository after another. But I found it is easy to miss something with too many repositories.

I also considered to create only one repository. The downside for me is that, I have several sample projects, the first clone needs download many unnecessary files for me.

What is the best repository structure so that I could manage my projects easily with Git? Or Git is fit for this kind of project scenario?

More accurate, here is a diagram that simulate my current structure on TFS.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

> Those projects will be regrouped into several products

You can create one Git repo per product, and in each product git repo, add those projects as **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

That way, you can clone only one repo, and start modifying each submodule repo in that one clone.

The only overhead is, for each submodule modification, to:

- add, commit and push inside that submodule
- go back to the parent product repo, add, commit and push (in order to record the new **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

Comment: I guess you mean `submodules` instead of `submmodules`. :-)

Comment: @skypjack I have fixed that typo.

Comment: I considered this way, but I think there is another overhead. For example like the complex project structure I attached above. When I opened "web_sample1", then add "product_web" and "product_core" as submodules. Those two repositories will be two subfolders inside of "web_sample1" folder. Then I switch to "web_sample2" and do the same reference. In this case, the "product_web" and "product_core" will have two copies in two sample folders. Is that right? or did I miss something?

Comment: @Howard no, that is the reverse: you open product_web, which as web_sample_xx submodules in it.

Comment: That is an option. But it doesn't make sence if we have many sample projects. When we use TFS, if we want to open solution "web_sample1", we only load three projects: "web_sample1", "product_web", "product_core". If use the reverse version, "web_sample1" becomes a submodule of "product_web", and "product_web" becomes a submodule of "product_core". If we want to debug "web_sample2", we need to add "web_sample2" as submodule of "product_web". Then the core folder will become large in the future if we have many sample projects to maintain. This is the issue we wanna figure out.

Comment: @Howard Then you can use your first approach and define submodule as a parent repo "web_project1_parent", with "web_project1", "product_web" and "product_core" in it. It is true that when opening "web_sample2_parent",  "product_web" and "product_core" will have two copies in two sample folders.